# Chamar mais de um script bat

Tags: script, cmd

Estou com uma situação bem chatinha e não consegui achar solução, eu tenho 2 scripts e os mesmos são chamados através de um outro, meu problema é que ele chama um e não o outro, um inicia um `tomcat` e o outro inicia um banco `hsql`. Alguém pode me ajudar ? Está assim:

```
@echo off

call start-tomcat.bat tgg
call start-hsql.bat tgg

@pause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se chamar os dois assim, iniciarão em janelas separadas:

```
@echo off

start start-tomcat.bat tgg
start start-hsql.bat tgg

@pause
```

Se chamar assim inciarão na mesma janela:

```
@echo off

start /b start-tomcat.bat tgg
start /b start-hsql.bat tgg

@pause
```

Comment: Show, muito obrigado.